# NullPointerException while working with stateful PartialFunction and collectFirst

Tags: regex, xml, scala, configuration

Consider this (very ugly code):

```
object ExternalReferences2 {
  import java.util.regex._

  implicit def symbol2string(sym: Symbol) = sym.name

  object Mapping {
    def fromXml(mapping: scala.xml.NodeSeq) = {
      new Mapping(mapping \ 'vendor text, 
                  mapping \ 'match text, 
                  mapping \ 'format text)
    }
  }
  case class Mapping(vendor: String, 
                     matches: String,
                     format: String) extends PartialFunction[String, String] {
    private val pattern = Pattern.compile(matches)
    private var _currentMatcher: Matcher = null
    private def currentMatcher = 
      { println("Getting matcher: " + _currentMatcher); _currentMatcher }
    private def currentMatcher_=(matcher: Matcher) = 
      { println("Setting matcher: " + matcher); _currentMatcher = matcher }

    def isDefinedAt(entity: String) = 
      { currentMatcher = pattern.matcher(entity); currentMatcher.matches }

    def apply(entity: String) = apply

    def apply = {
      val range = 0 until currentMatcher.groupCount()
      val groups = range 
                     map (currentMatcher.group(_)) 
                     filterNot (_ == null) 
                     map (_.replace('.', '/'))
      format.format(groups: _*)
    }
  }

  val config =
    <external-links>
      <mapping>
        <vendor>OpenJDK</vendor>
        <match>{ """^(javax?|sunw?|com.sun|org\.(ietf\.jgss|omg|w3c\.dom|xml\.sax))(\.[^.]+)+$""" }</match>
        <format>{ "http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/%s.html" }</format>
      </mapping>
    </external-links>

  def getLinkNew(entity: String) =
     (config \ 'mapping) 
       collectFirst({ case m => Mapping.fromXml(m)})
       map(_.apply)

  def getLinkOld(entity: String) =
    (config \ 'mapping).view 
      map(m => Mapping.fromXml(m)) 
      find(_.isDefinedAt(entity)) 
      map(_.apply)
}
```

I tried to improve the `getLinkOld` method by using `collectFirst` as shown in `getLinkNew`, but I always get a `NullPointerException` because `_currentMatcher` is still set to `null`

```
scala> ExternalReferences2.getLinkNew("java.util.Date")
Getting matcher: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ExternalReferences2$Mapping.apply(<console>:32)
    at ExternalReferences2$$anonfun$getLinkNew$2.apply(<console>:58)
    at ExternalReferences2$$anonfun$getLinkNew$2.apply(<console>:58)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:131)
    at ExternalReferences2$.getLinkNew(<console>:58)
    at .<init>(<console>:13)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
```

while it works perfectly with `getLinkOld`.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matcher is created as a side-effect in `isDefined`. Passing side effecting functions to routine such as `map` is usually a recipe for disaster, but this is not even what happens here. Your code requires `isDefined` to have been called just before `apply` is, with the same argument. That makes your code very fragile, and that is what you should change.

Clients of `PartialFunction` do not have to do follow that protocol in general. Imagine for instance

```
if (f.isDefinedAt(x) && f.isDefinedAt(y)) {fx = f(x); fy = f(y)}.
```

And here the code that calls `apply` is not even yours, but the collection classes', so you do not control what happens.

Your specific problem in `getLinkNew` is that `isDefined` is simply never called.The `PartialFunction` argument of `collectFirst` is `{case m => ...}`. The `isDefined` that is called is the `isDefined` of this function. As `m` is an irrefutable pattern, it is allways true, and collectFirst will always return the first element if there is one. That the partial function returns another partial function (the `Mapping`) which happens not to be defined at `m`, is irrelevant.

**Edit - Possible workaround**

A very light change would be to check whether a `matcher` is available and create it if it is not. Better, keep the `entity` string that has been used to create it too, so that you can check it is the proper one. This should make the side effect benign as long as there is no multithreading. But the way, do not use `null`, use `Option`, so the compiler will not let you ignore the possibility that it may be `None`.

```
var _currentMatcher : Option[(String, Matcher)] = None
def currentMatcher(entity: String) : Matcher = _currentMatcher match{
  case Some(e,m) if e == entity => m
  case _ => {
    _currentMatcher = (entity, pattern.matcher(entity))
    _currentmatcher._2
  }
}
```

**Edit again. Stupid me**

Sorry, the so called workaround indeed makes the class safer, but it does not make the `collectFirst` solution work. Again, the `case m =>` partial function is always defined (note: `entity` does not even appears in your `getLinkNew` code, which should be worrying). The problem is that one would need a PartialFunction of a NodeSeq (not of entity, which will be known to the function, but not passed as argument). isDefined will be called, then apply. The pattern and the matcher depends on the NodeSeq, so they cannnot be created beforehand, but only in isDefined and/or apply. In the same spirit, you can cache what is computed in isDefined to reuse in Apply. This is definitely not pretty

```
def linkFor(entity: String) = new PartialFunction[NodeSeq, String] {
  var _matcher : Option[String, Matcher] = None
  def matcher(regexp: String) = _matcher match {
    case Some(r, m) where r == regexp => m
    case None => {
      val pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp)
      _matcher = (regexp, pattern.matcher(entity))
      _matcher._2
    }
  }
  def isDefined(mapping: NodeSeq) = {
    matcher(mapping \ "match" text).matches
  }
  def apply(mapping: NodeSeq) = {
     // call matcher(...), it is likely to reuse previous matcher, build result
  }

}
```

You use that with `(config \ mapping).collectFirst(linkFor(entity))`

Comment: Thanks! What would be a good solution in your opinion which doesn't compute things twice?

Comment: Proposed one workaround that does minimal changes to your code, not as a comment to have more room.